# Call a link from APEX

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

Assume a URL link (containing a merge field on the Account object) exist on the Account object with the API Name link_1, and I have a VF Page with a standrdcontroller on Account, is there a way to call link_1 from the controller or when the page loads, the goal here is to invoke that link programtically once the controller and action are completed.

Answer (score 0):

And what do you mean by invoke? Redirect user to that linked page? Pull that page's content and somehow display? Get page's content, save to PDF and put in Attachment in Salesforce for example?

Actions that can be bound in Visualforce are supposed to return [`PageReference`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm). Most of the time you return null or mark the method as void, you want to stay on current VF page (maybe there's something else you want the user to do, maybe there were errors and you want to display them on same page so user has chance to fix them). But for you it could be

```
public PageReference doSomething(){
    // Your action code here
    // ...
    PageReference pr = new PageReference(acc.Link_1__c);
    return pr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the API name of the URL link on Account (Account Custom Button or Link
) is Loan_Collateral_report_LINK_TEST and the line of code in line 55 is PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(Acc.Loan_Collateral_report_LINK_TEST);      I got the following error                Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Loan_Collateral_report_LINK_TEST at line 55 column 54

Comment: Most custom fields in SF end with `__c`. So in constructor you need something like `acc = [SELECT Loan_Collateral_report_LINK_TEST__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :sc.getId()];` (assuming sc is your `StandardController` passed to constructor. And then in pagereference go `acc.Loan_Collateral_report_LINK_TEST__c `. If you still struggle - post your code